Debugging NextJs 14 Server: Visual Studio Code / pnpm / turbo.json in apps/www
I cloned this repo (https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui) and tried to debug some server side code in Visual Studio code with no luck.
I followed this guide: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging
And also tried different launch configurations of https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/62008, none worked.
Is someone able to create a launch.json file with a working config?
